# How to switch between fullwidth and halfwidth in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I was writing some code recently, I accidentally pressed some combination of keys and now every input in Visual Studio Code becomes like this:

[image]

which is apparently **impossible to compile**, and currently, the only way to solve this is to restart the computer. What's curious is that **when I type text in other editors (Word, notepad, etc.)**, the display is normal. I also **tried the hot key in word, which is `shift+space`**, but it still didn't work. Can anyone help with this annoying issue?

Comment: seems like `"editor.letterSpacing"` has changed.

Comment: font-family and font-size have changed as well.

Comment: the letterspacing is set as 0, which I don't think is relevant. And as shown on the picture, the font family or font size couldn't have changed because the second line, which I just pasted from notepad, appears to be fine.

Comment: that box is also used for suspicious Unicode characters